# Issue with css wrap div in another div

Tags: html, css

This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            div.p > div
            {
                width: 200px;
                height: 30px;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #FF0;
                transform: rotate(40deg);
                top: 45px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 45px;
            }
            div.p
            {
                width:200px;
                height:300px;
                background-color:red;
                border:2px solid black;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="p">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

please check this image https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wrivi3760l3t7f/123.jpg

I want to remove the corner of yellow div so it should not go out from its parent div and I want to use this type of box in my site for feature products I have tried many things but I'm unable to do it!

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrodriguezr/AK2LD/1/)

```
div.p
   {
      width:200px;
      height:300px;
      background-color:red;
      border:2px solid black;
      overflow: hidden;
      position:absolute;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside:

```
div.p
```

Insert:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Also, use this in `div.p > div` for IE 9+ support :)

```
-ms-transform: rotate(40deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing.

Your inner  is positioned with display: absolute, thus it is not within the document flow.

I assume therefor overflow:hidden does not apply.

However try the following:
Move overflow:hidden to .p not to the inner div

If this does not work I would use three divs instead, a third one as border and use z-order.